# The method fillColor() is undefined?

Tags: android, google-maps

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .radius(1000); // In meters
            .fillColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
            .strokeWidth(2);
```

I keep getting the same error at fillColor, strokeColor and strokeWidth

Eclipse doesn't give me any options to import anything. Any idea what could be wrong please?

```
The method fillColor(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be a ; after radius(1000)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the location of the semicolon to the end of your chain. You're ending your statement prematurely, which is why the compiler attempts to find `fillColor()` in `MainActivity` rather than `CircleOptions`.

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
            .radius(1000) // In meters
            .fillColor(Color.RED)
            .strokeColor(Color.BLACK)
            .strokeWidth(2);
```

Comment: I said move the semicolon, *not* add another one. Take out the semicolon after `radius(1000)`